# AngularJS adding empty option list in ionic hybrid app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-options

I'm working on a hybrid mobile app using the ionic framework. There is one situation where I need to show 2 drop-down list in the ionic alert box. One is for showing 'Year' list & another one is for 'Month' list.

Then, the user needs to select 'Year' from year dropdown list & 'Month' from Month dropdown list and click on View button. After, click on View button I need to process data by using selected Year & Month value.

Here is a screenshot of my app with 2 dropdown button.

[image]

Everything working fine except one situation where if a user has selected any option from 'Month' list & click on 'Year' dropdown to select any 'Year' value then, my Month list repopulates with adding one extra option in Month list & it's visible like this -

[image]

Screenshot from chrome consol -

[image]

I've created one Jsfiddle with same logic which I'm using for my hybrid app. But, at there it's working fine. But, the same thing in my app it's not working.

Here is the JSfiddle link -

I think, it's something related to Ionic & Angular scope related issue. But, don't know what exactly it is. Need some help.

**Angular JS version in my app** : 1.4.3

**Ionic Configuration** - Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.21
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 
Node Version: v4.1.2

Regards

Comment: can u give me a fiddle?

Comment: Don't know why SF is not accepting my JSfiddle link but, here it is that - https://jsfiddle.net/mi6crazyheart/masge8wx/20/

Comment: can u declare this  $scope.payMonthList=[]; in Your updateMonthList () function ?

Comment: try it . it ll be refresh the scope payMonthList  array .

Comment: I've already tried that one. It's not working.